# libPods.a library missing in Cocoa Pods Beta

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I am currently using cocoapods beta. I installed one pod which automatically installed libPods.a and added it to the project. I then added SwiftyJSON to the project and then I found that libPods.a was replaced with Pods.framework. Because the other pod requires libPods.a, the project is no longer compiling.

Please Help!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you run `YourProjectName.xcworkspace` instead `YourProjectName.xcodeproj`.